# Create list from pandas dataframe for distinct values in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

From the following Pandas dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id': [102,102,102,303,303,944,944,944,944],'A':[1.2,1.2,1.2,0.8,0.8,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0],'B':[1.8,1.8,1.8,1.0,1.0,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2],
                  'A_scored_time':[10,25,0,33,0,40,0,90,0],'B_scored_time':[0,0,30,0,41,0,75,0,95]})
```

I was trying to create lists deriving from the combinations of `['A_scored_time','B_scored_time']`, to obtain the following lists corresponding with unique `Id`:

```
Id(102) = A_Time = [10,25],      B_Time = [30]
Id(303) = A_Time = [33],         B_Time = [41]
Id(944) = A_Time = [40,90],      B_Time = [75,95]
```

This lists will be applied in the function below.

```
x1 = [1,0,0] 
x2 = [0,1,0] 
x3 = [0,0,1]

k = 100 # constant
total_timeslot = 100 # same as k
A_Time = []  
B_Time = []
```

For i in range(distinct Id), df has 3 distinct Id here. For each i the probability array y.

```
y = np.array([1-(A + B)/k, A/k, B/k])  


def sum_squared_diff(x1, x2, x3, y):
    ssd = []
    for k in range(total_timeslot):  
        if k in A_Time:
            ssd.append(sum((x2 - y) ** 2))
        elif k in B_Time:
            ssd.append(sum((x3 - y) ** 2))
        else:
            ssd.append(sum((x1 - y) ** 2))
    return ssd
```

The output will be an array of len k. Once I acquire this, I will sum all n(n distinct Id) arrays. Which is what I'm after.
The outcome for `df` is:

```
Id(102) = sum(sum_squared_diff(x1, x2, x3, y))  =5.872800000000018
Id(303) = sum(sum_squared_diff(x1, x2, x3, y))  = 3.9407999999999896
Id(944) = sum(sum_squared_diff(x1, x2, x3, y))  =7.760800000000006
```

Giving `toatl sum = 17.574400000000015.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the question in your title use:

```
df.groupby('Id')[['A_scored_time','B_scored_time']]\
  .agg(lambda x: x[x != 0].tolist())\
  .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    Id A_scored_time B_scored_time
0  102      [10, 25]          [30]
1  303          [33]          [41]
2  944      [40, 90]      [75, 95]
```

Comment: Thank you Scott, This solves the first half of my problem. How can I link this with the function where y is constructed by each unique Id?

Comment: @A.Abs I don't understand the second parts of this question.

Comment: @A.Abs Sorry, that didn't help any.  Maybe someone else could understand more clearly.